# Swift Universal Links not calling the AppDelegate's function

Tags: swiftui, ios-universal-links

I'm pretty new and inexperienced with SwiftUI.
This is the first time I try to implement universal links to my app, and after hours of debugging I still cant figure out why it's not working.

I have my AASA file hosted on firebase hosting, it uses https, it's delivered as application/json, and apple's cdn fetched it as it was supposed to.

My file looks like this

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
          {
              "appID": "TEAMID.BUNDLEID",
              "paths": [
                "/openApp",
                "/shareDeck/*"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

But I also tried the way it's shown in the documentation:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "TEAMID.BUNDLEID",
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/openApp/",
            "comment": "Matches open app url"
          },
          {
            "/": "/shareDeck/*",
            "comment": "Matches share deck url"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The file is hosted on quiziqo.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association, and checking `https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/quiziqo.com` I can see that apple's CDN got the updated document.

Using a AASA validator online, it says that everything is fine with my file.

I, of course, added `applinks:quiziqo.com` to the project's associated domains.
I also run a diagnosis of the device I'm running the app on, and got:

```
Service:              applinks
App ID:               TEAMID.BUNDLEID
App Version:          1.0
App PI:               <LSPersistentIdentifier 0xca28a2f50> { v = 0, t = 0x8, u = 0xabc, db = 61C39825-07F7-44EB-938B-C4288D0474FF, {length = 8, bytes = 0xbc0a000000000000} }
Domain:               quiziqo.com
Patterns:             {"/":"/openApp/"}, {"/":"/shareDeck/*"}
User Approval:        unspecified
Site/Fmwk Approval:   approved
Flags:                
Last Checked:         2023-08-07 17:47:13 +0000
Next Check:           2023-08-12 17:35:57 +0000
```

So it appears that the device "approved" the link, and it should work.

If I click on an universal link, it correctly opens the app, and testing the same link in the developer menu, results in "Opens Installed Application", with the associated and correct identifier.

The problem is that I need to run some code when the link is received, and use the query parameters it has. To do this i have

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
    {
        
        // Get URL components from the incoming user activity.
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
              let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
              let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
            return false
        }
        
        
        // Check for specific URL components that you need.
        guard let path = components.path,
              let params = components.queryItems else {
            return false
        }
        print("path = \(path)")
        
        
        if let token = params.first(where: { $0.name == "token" })?.value,
           let deckId = params.first(where: { $0.name == "deckId" })?.value {
            
            print("token = \(token)")
            print("deckId = \(deckId)")
            return true
            
            
            
        } else {
            print("Error")
            return false
        }
    }
```

In my app delegate.
Of course, now it should only log some stuff, but it doesn't. Any breakpoint set in this function is not being hit, even if the app launches when clicking the link.
This is the same function copied from Apple's documentation, and I only changed the parameters' names, all the rest is exactly the same.
Even introducing a print before the first guard runs, results in nothing printed, meaning that the function is not even called.

I tried rebooting, cleaning the build folder, reinstalling. Unfortunately I don't have another device to try.
Trying it in the simulator doesn't work either.

Weirdly enough, when I open the link, every time, and only in that case, I get

```
10.12.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (11b018908) Stream error: 'Unavailable: Network connectivity changed'
```

I make use of firebase, but the universal link function is not related in any way to firebase.

I don't even know what else to try, I read every post about this, but none of them gave a solution that worked for me.

I'm on Xcode 15 beta 5, and iPadOS 17.0 developer beta.

The function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
    {
[...]
}
```

Should run whenever the app is opened from a universal link.